# Ionic Display and Modals - slow and buggy even on fast phone

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework

I have edited the starter template for ionic and everything works great in the -lab environment.  However when I run the application on an actual phone the usability is diminished by speed and performance.

```
<script id="templates/landingModalRegister.html" type="text/ng-template">
            <ion-modal-view class="">
                <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-dark">
                  <button class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="showRegister.hide()">Cancel</button>
                </ion-header-bar>
                <ion-content class="registerModal" scroll="false">

                    <form ng-submit="register()" style="margin-top: 150px">
                        <label class="item item-input landingInput">
                            <span class="input-label">Username</span>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="registerData.username">
                        </label>
                        <label class="item item-input landingInput">
                            <span class="input-label">Password</span>
                            <input type="password" ng-model="registerData.password">
                        </label>
                        <label class="item item-input landingInput">
                            <span class="input-label">Retype password</span>
                            <input type="password" ng-model="registerData.password2">
                        </label>
                        <label class="item item-input item-select landingInput">
                            <div class="input-label">
                                Account Type
                            </div>
                            <select ng-model="registerData.type">
                                <option>Client</option>
                                <option selected>Admin</option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                        <label class="item landingInput">
                            <button class="button button-block button-balanced" type="submit">Register</button>
                        </label>
                    </form>
                </ion-content>
            </ion-modal-view>
```

Take for instance this modal view initiated by an onclick function.  This modal will not open on an older phone (Samsung Avant) and on a newer phone (Nexus 6p) it opens but slowly and not smooth.  I used the device inspector to check errors and nothing is apparent and the same device-like jerky behavior is present - this is smooth in the lab environment.

Another question I have is how to optimize pictures properly - when using higher resolution images (I scaled them to the device dimensions) the backgrounds still visibly draw on the page.

Is there any thing that I'm missing to get this closer to native performance?

Edit: Here is my code for implementing the modal.

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/landingModalRegister.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
}).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.showRegister = modal;
});

$scope.openRegister = function () {
    $scope.showRegister.show();
}
```

Comment: May be are you using a lot of css gradients, box shadows and so on?

Comment: @manzapanza This was great info - I thought the issue was with box-shadow only.  I took off all filters that I had on the backgrounds and it did the trick - there is still a delay when activating the modals thats giving a non-native feel - is there any way to speed this up as well?

Comment: Please, show the js code of your modal implementation

Comment: @manzapanza I have added the js code as well.

Comment: Your implementation seems ok. Try removing all custom css to see if this delay disappear. Are you using templatecache?

Comment: @manzapanza I fixed the issue by removing all of the css and back customizations one at a time.  Now this is responsive even on my slower phone.  I had never heard of templatecache and did some research and found that some people found that it did not significantly add to the speed of their app.  Would you recommend templatecache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be are you using a lot of css gradients, box shadows and so on?

Try removing all custom css to see if this delay disappear.

Other tips:

- [Implement templatecache](https://github.com/miickel/gulp-angular-templatecache)
- [Speed Up Your Ionic Application Using These Techniques](http://www.gajotres.net/speed-up-your-ionic-application-using-these-techniques/)